# find function in a module

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following module

module.js

```
  var Instance = (function () {

    jsfunc('fn');

    var fn = function () {
      console.log('this in fn');
    }

  }());
```

jsfunc.js

```
  function jsfunc(fn) {
    // how to find if fn is defined in Instance module
  }
```

As I am passing string, which is a function inside `instance` module. And then I want to check if that `jsfunc`'s parameter function is defined inside `Instance`. **How can I achieve this?**

Answer (score 4):

You need pass a function reference instead of a function name, since it is in a closure scope

```
var Instance = (function () {

    var fn = function () {
        console.log('this in fn');
    }

    jsfunc(fn);

}());

function jsfunc(fn) {
    // how to find if fn is defined in Instance module
    if (typeof fn == 'function') {
        fn()
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lp8ZG/)

Also note that the value of `Instance` will be `undefined` since there is no value returned from the anonymous function.

Comment: He is JScript ,JQuery genious ,machine! :)

Comment: I want to pass string not function reference.

Comment: @2619 any specific reason to do so? unless they are in a shared scope there is nothing much that can be done....

Comment: The reason is that I will pass an object instead with key/value pairs instead of only one string. The value of those objects would be string.

Comment: @2619 if you can explain really what you are trying to do then we can have a look at how it can be achieved... in all languages there will be some limitations which are imposed on it we always can find some workaround by making some compromises

Comment: @2619 then probably you should share a sample of that... even better if you can edit the fiddle I created to recreate the problem.... but accessing or checking something which is in an isolated scope is not possible

Comment: Isn't it possible to get the scope in which `jsfunc` is called and then find that particular function?